# Javascript timezone gives error in laravel carbon method

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I get user time zone in react using moment.tz.guess() method and pass it to Laravel in axios but when I try to create date in controller using carbon create from format method it throw error on time zone

I expect date should be created with carbon

```
 params ={
        startDate:moment().subtract(event.target.value, 'd').startOf('day').format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        endDate:moment().subtract(1, 'd').endOf('day').format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        timezone:user.timezone ? user.timezone:moment.tz.guess()
     }
dateFilter(params,event.target.value);

const dateFilter =(params,range)=>{
setShowSkeleton(true);
setShowOrderSkeleton(true);
setShowSkeletonTable(true);
setShowTrafficSkeleton(true);
setShowCutliveSkeleton(true);

let from ='';
let to = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

if(range=='custom'){
  from= moment(params.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  to=moment(params.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
if(range !='custom'){
  if(range=='all'){
    from= '';
    to=moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
  else if(range=='today'){
    from= moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    to=moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
  else{
    from= moment().subtract(range, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    to=moment().subtract(1,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
}
get_total_orders(from,to);
 
  if(keyword !='' && !params.keyword){
      params.keyword=keyword;
  }
  if(sortBy != ''){
    params.sort_type = sortType;
    params.sort_by   = sortBy;
  }
  if(!params.page){
    params.page=page;
  }
  let uri = '/filter/date';
  if(params.days && params.days=='all'){
    uri ='/analytics';
  }
  axiosInterceptor.get(uri,{params:
      params
  }).then((response)=>{
    let data =response.data;
    if(params.days && params.days=='all'){
      setTotalLinks(data.links.length);
      setLinks(data.short_url_data.data);
      setLinksCount(data.links.length);
      setShowOrderSkeleton(false);
    }
    else{
      setTotalLinks('-');
      setLinksCount(data.links.length);
      setLinks(data.short_url_data);
      setShowOrderSkeleton(false);
    }
    let trafficIds = [];
    let cutlivedIds=[];
    let ShortUrlIds=[]; 
    data.links.forEach(link => {
        ShortUrlIds.push(link.id);
        if(link.traffic_id >0){
          trafficIds.push(link.short_url_code);
        }
        else if(link.cutlive_id > 0 ){
          cutlivedIds.push(link.cutlive_id);

        }
    });
    
    get_orders(ShortUrlIds.join(','),from,to);
    get_cutlive_clicks(cutlivedIds.join(','),from,to);
    get_total_clicks(cutlivedIds.join(','),trafficIds.join(','),from,to);
    get_visitors(trafficIds.join(','),from,to);
    get_pageviews(trafficIds.join(','),from,to);
    get_realtimeStats(trafficIds.join(','));
    get_events(ShortUrlIds.join(','),from,to);
    //setShowSkeletonTable(false);
    
    
  });
```

}

/*------- Controller function part --------*/

```
 $startDate  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->startDate,$request->timezone);
            $startDate->setTimezone('UTC');
            $startDate = $startDate->toDateTimeString();
```

/*------output --------*/
timezone get from js "America/New_York" when I dump timezone from request

Does anyone know where is a problem. I can't share more code due to restrictions from my employer.

Comment: Show your code. We cannot help you if we can't recreate your issue. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76484277/edit) and include your JS\Moment and PHP\Carbon code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, plus please also provide an example of result that `moment.tz.guess()` gives you and so the exact strings that you pass to Carbon, and the exact error you get.